# Duplicate Key Error in Sass

Tags: sass

I'm trying to build the [Figuration](http://figuration.org/get-started/build-tools/) source files and am running into this error:

```
Running "sass:core" (sass) task
>> Error: Duplicate key 1_5 in map (0: x: 0, y: 0, 0_25: x: $spacer-x * .25,
y: $spacer-y * .25, 0_5: x: $spacer-x * .5, y: $spacer-y * .5, 1: x: $spacer-
x, y: $spacer-y, 1_5: x: $spacer-x * 1.5, y: $spacer-y * 1.5, 2: x: $spacer-x 
* 2, y: $spacer-y * 2).
>>         on line 138 of scss/_settings.scss
>> >> $spacers: (
>>    ----------^
```

However, in `_settings.scss` the offending map looks fine to me:

```
$spacers: (
0: (
    x: 0,
    y: 0
),
0_25: (
    x: ($spacer-x * .25),
    y: ($spacer-y * .25)
),
0_5: (
    x: ($spacer-x * .5),
    y: ($spacer-y * .5)
),
1: (
    x: $spacer-x,
    y: $spacer-y
),
1_5: (
    x: ($spacer-x * 1.5),
    y: ($spacer-y * 1.5)
),
2: (
    x: ($spacer-x * 2),
    y: ($spacer-y * 2)
)
) !default;
```

Googling has only turned up issues for much older versions of SASS and claims that it's been fixed, so I'm at a loss.

`sass -v` confirms I'm using selective steve.

Answer (score 2):

Enclosing the keys in quotation marks did the trick.